# php + ajax + json что-то не отображается

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Здравствуйте, делаю поиск по имени...

В php всё работает, а вот с js не могу разобраться  В id="playerMenu" ничего не появляется

Php код:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблемный код js:

```
        function searchPlayer(name) {
        if ( name.length < 3 || name.length > 30 ) return;

        var playerList = document.getElementById('playerMenu');

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/check",
            data: {
                nickname: name
            }, 
            dataType: "json"

        }, function( json ) {


            if ( json.status == 'success' ) {
                var list = '';
                for ( var i = 0, Max = json.players.length - 1; i < Max; i ++ ) {
                    var player = json.players[i];
                    list += '<a href="#">'+ player.name +'</a>';
                }

                if ( list != '' ) {
                    playerList.innerHTML = list;
                } else {
                    playerList.innerHTML = 'Игроки не найдены';
                }
            } else {
                playerList.innerHTML = 'Ошибка: ' + json.message;
            }

        });
    }
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" style="width: 300px" onkeyup="searchPlayer(this.value)" />
```

---

```
success: function(json){

...

},
```

Comment: `echo json_encode($json); exit();`

Comment: всё-ровно, тут что-то с JS

Comment: так открой консоль и посмотри что там пишет...... в конце концов напиши при получении `console.log(json);` и посмотри что выведет

Comment: спасибо, понял. 
success: funtion(json)

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса